# Помогите разобраться с куками и js

Tags: javascript, cookie

Добрый день!

Прошу помощи. Есть код:

```
document.cookie = "yap";
if (document.cookie == "yap") {
        alert("yap");
        document.getElementById("pas").value == "111";
    }
    function checkPas () {
            if (document.getElementById("pas").value == "111") {
                    $( "#conteinerPas" ).hide( "drop", { direction: "left" }, "slow"  );    
                    $( "nav" ).delay(1000).show( "fade",  "slow"  );
                    $("body").css("overflow","");   
                    document.cookie = "yap";
                }
            else {
                    $( "form" ).effect( "shake", 500 );
                    var obj=document.getElementById("pas");
                    obj.value="Пароль не верный";
                }
            }
```

на html

```
   <div id="conteinerPas">
       <section>
            <article>
            <img src="img/logo.gif">
            <br />
                <form>
                    <input type="text" name="" placeholder="пароль" id="pas" />
                    <input type="button" name="" value="Вход" onclick="checkPas ()">
                </form>
            </article>
       </section>
   </div>
```

Задача состоит в том, чтобы при наличии куков блок проверки пароля не появлялся.

Пожалуйста, объясните почему #conteinerPas все равно отображается сразу. Как исправить?

Самое смешное то, что даже если я пишу вот так:

```
if (document.cookie == "yap") {
                    $( "#conteinerPas" ).hide( "drop", { direction: "left" }, "slow"  );    
                    $( "nav" ).delay(1000).show( "fade",  "slow"  );
                    $("body").css("overflow","");
    }
```

## conteinerPas все равно отображаться.

Верю, надеюсь, жду )

Comment: Через `document.cookie` получишь строку типа этой: `_ga=GA1.2.126757503.1423171083; _gat=1`, т.е. научись правильно устанавливать/читать куки [отсюда.](https://learn.javascript.ru/cookie)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сразу после того, как устанавливаешь куку, посмотри, что получается:

```
console.log(document.cookie);
```

Воспользуйся функциями чтения/установки куки из этой статьи: https://learn.javascript.ru/cookie

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

Comment: На каком моменте выпадает ошибка? Посмотри пример использования функций: https://jsfiddle.net/wuh8qttt/2/